# Show all post content on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, show

Im using the theme HTML 5 Blank (http://html5blank.com/) with WordPress 3.7.1.
On my page I want to display everthing from the posts, text and images.
In the settings in wordpress admin i have it set on show hole post but it does not work.
I have olso deleted the php code in the loop that inserts the excerpt from the theme. Sitt not workning. Any ideas? I can send code if you want, for now i do not know what code can be usefull.

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<?php the_excerpt() ?>`and add the following code to your theme's loop.

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

That should display the content, rather that the excerpt.